# ¿como puedo desplegar todos los campos de mi api en React usando axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Estoy intentando desplegar toda la informacion de mi BD en mi componente AgregarPedido con el fin de poder mostrar todos los platillos al usuario, actualmente ya logre hacer que se muestren todos los nombres de los platillos disponibles pero al momento de querer mostrar la demas informacion (nombre, precio y folio) tengo demasiados errores o al final no me termina mostrando nada, el siguiente codigo es mi api la cual esta hecha en js:

```
app.get('/menu', (req, res) => {
    const query = 'SELECT nombreplatillo, precio, folioproducto FROM menu';
    connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error al obtener los nombres de platillos:', err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al obtener los nombres de platillos' });
            return;
        }
        const nombresPlatillos = result.map((row) => row.nombreplatillo);
        const precioPlatillos = result.map((row) => row.precio);
        const folioPlatillos = result.map((row) => row.folioproducto);

        res.json({ nombresPlatillos, precioPlatillos, folioPlatillos  });
    });
});
```

como se puede ver en el api estot mandando a llamar tanto al nombre, precio y folio de manera correcta, pero hasta ahora solo he podido mostrar solamente el nombre, el siguiente codigo es como esta hecho mi componente donde mando a llamar a esa api para mostrar todo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Styles/AgregarPedido.css';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import axios from 'axios';

function AgregarPedido() {
    const [nombreplatillo, setnombreplatillo] = useState('');
    const [precio, setPrecioplatillo] = useState('');
    const [folio, setFolioplatillo] = useState('');


    const [cantidad, setcantidad] = useState('');
    const [fecha, setfecha] = useState('');
    const [platillos, setPlatillos] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        obtenerPlatillos();
        setfecha(getCurrentDate()); // Establecer la fecha actual al cargar el componente
    }, []);

    const obtenerPlatillos = () => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:3000/menu')
            .then((response) => {
                setPlatillos(response.data.nombresPlatillos);
                setPrecioplatillo(response.data.precio);
                setTotalPages(Math.ceil(response.data.nombresPlatillos.length / 6));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: 'Al parecer hay un problema con el internet!',
                });
            });
    };

    const getCurrentDate = () => {
        const now = new Date();
        const year = now.getFullYear();
        let month = now.getMonth() + 1;
        let day = now.getDate();

        if (month < 10) {
            month = `0${month}`;
        }

        if (day < 10) {
            day = `0${day}`;
        }

        return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    };

    const handleAgregarClick = () => {
        if (isNaN(cantidad) || parseFloat(cantidad) <= 0) {
            Swal.fire('Error', 'Ingrese una cantidad válida', 'error');
            return;
        }

        Swal.fire({
            title: '¿Deseas agregar este producto?',
            text: 'Dar de alta un producto en el menú',
            icon: 'question',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, agregar',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                try {
                    axios
                        .post('http://localhost:3000/ventas', {
                            nombreplatillo: nombreplatillo,
                            cantidad: parseInt(cantidad),
                            fecha: new Date(fecha),
                        })
                        .then((response) => {
                            Swal.fire('¡Agregado!', response.data.message, 'success').then(
                                () => {
                                    /* window.location.reload();*/
                                }
                            );
                        });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    Swal.fire('Error', 'Error al agregar el dato', 'error');
                }
            }
        });
    };

    const handlePlatilloClick = (platillo) => {
        setnombreplatillo(platillo);
    };

    const handlePrevPage = () => {
        setCurrentPage((prevPage) => prevPage - 1);
    };

    const handleNextPage = () => {
        setCurrentPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
    };

    const visiblePlatillos = platillos.slice(
        (currentPage - 1) * 5,
        currentPage * 5
    );

    return (
        <div className="scroll-container">

            <div className="platillo-form-container">

                <h2>Ingrese un platillo y la cantidad</h2>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="nombrePlatillo">Nombre del Platillo:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="nombrePlatillo"
                        value={nombreplatillo}
                        onChange={(e) => setnombreplatillo(e.target.value)}
                        readOnly
                    />
                    <ul className="platillos-list">
                        {visiblePlatillos.map((platillo, index) => (
                            <li key={index} onClick={() => handlePlatilloClick(platillo)}>
                                {platillo}
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>

                {totalPages > 1 && (
                    <div className="pagination">
                        {currentPage > 1 && (
                            <button className="pagination-button" onClick={handlePrevPage}>
                                Anterior
                            </button>
                        )}
                        {currentPage < totalPages && (
                            <button className="pagination-button" onClick={handleNextPage}>
                                Siguiente
                            </button>
                        )}
                    </div>
                )}

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        id="cantidad"
                        value={cantidad}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            const inputPrice = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                            setcantidad(inputPrice);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="fecha">Fecha de servicio</label>
                    <input
                        type="date"
                        id="fecha"
                        value={fecha}
                        onChange={(e) => setfecha(e.target.value)}
                        readOnly
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" onClick={handleAgregarClick}>
                    Agregar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AgregarPedido;
```

como se puede apreciar ya implemente las variables donde se guardara esa informacion, pero de ahi ya no se que mas poder hacer, en la funcion obtener platillos es la encargada de mandar a llamar a mi api usando axios, me podrian dar alguna solucion o recomendacion para poder mostrar toda la informacion.

Comment: Estás descomponiendo la respuesta de la base de datos en listas diferentes cuya única relación sería posible a través de el índice de las mismas.

Comment: No se de React pero viendo la petición en Axios se me hace raro (y realmente no lo entiendo) ver que separes el nombre, precio y folio de cada platillo, a mi parecer no tiene sentido y cómo está en el comentario anterior ¿como lo vas a relacionar? Al momento de agregar una orden ¿como vas a saber cuál es su respectivo indice y precio?

Comment: En el componente que proporcione, se utilizan diferentes apis, las cuales tienen diferentes relaciones con diferentes datos de mi BD, en este caso solo estoy trabajando en la api de menu, la cual se llama en la funcion obtenerPlatillos